# some join insert into same table foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have one table with some foreign keys of other tables. I dont know how insert normal values and values of foreign keys.
I want insert one row with one column of one foreign key and two columns of other foreign key.

The question is how i do the insert in table 'user'?

My tables are:

### table CITY

```
id_city (pk)   |    nom_city 
--------------------------------
     1                new york
```

### table FOOD

```
id_food (pk)   |    nom_food   
--------------------------------
     1                fish 
     2                meat
```

And I want to create this table:

### table USER

```
id_user (pk)   |    nom_user   |   id_city(fk)   |   id_food(fk)   |   id_food(fk)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1                ana               1                 1              2
```

Thanks and sorry for my english :)

Comment: The question is how i do the insert in table 'user'?

Comment: Is your question how to write an insert statement in SQL? Have you searched for solutions already?

Comment: What's wrong with a normal insert ? : INSERT INTO USER (ID_USER, NOM_USER, ID_CITY, ID_FOOD_1, ID_FOOD_2) VALUES (1, 'ana', 1, 1, 2)

Comment: Is the question how to `INSERT` or how to `CREATE` the table `user`?

Comment: My table 'User' was created: 
CREATE TABLE USER (
id_user int not null auto_increment primary key,
nom_user varchar(100),
id_city int(5),
id_food int(5),

foreign key (id_city) references city (id_city),
foreign key (id_food) references city (id_food)
);

Comment: There is something wrong in the logic if your E/R model

Answer (score 0):

You use a simple insert statement. The statement is not affected by the foreign keys however an error will be thrown if the foreign keys are violated. i.e they do not exist in your other table.

Comment: My table 'User' was created: 
CREATE TABLE USER (
id_user int not null auto_increment primary key,
nom_user varchar(100),
id_city int(5),
id_food int(5),

foreign key (id_city) references city (id_city),
foreign key (id_food) references city (id_food)
);